# Applications/Xcode vs Developer/Applications/Xcode

Tags: xcode, spotlight

I have OSX 10.8 with Xcode 4.6.3 installed (it shows under App Store). When I Spotlight-search "xcode" I see two results: `Xcode – Mac` & `Xcode – Developer`.

The first launches as expected, but with the second I get the following warning: "This installation of Xcode 4.2 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. Install a version of the Xcode Tools that supports Mac OS X 10.8." and it quits instantly. Same if I try to launch via finder at `Developer/Applications/Xcode`.

I find this confusing - why does the app show twice and is there a way of removing the non-functioning version?

To further complicate matters, I have a folder `Developer-3.2.4` containing this version of Xcode which also shows in Spotlight results - I followed a tutorial to keep an older version of Xcode when the buggy new version 4 was released. I assume I can safely delete that now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have upgraded your system with older versions of Xcode present on it and missed uninstalling Xcode 4.2 while installing Xcode 4.3.

Xcode from version 4.3 onwards installs under `/Applications`. Only versions older than this (like your Xcode 4.2) install under `/Developer`. If you do not plan to boot OS X Lion from another disk/partition and use Xcode 4.2, you can safely uninstall it (do not just delete the folder from Finder).

To uninstall Xcode 4.2:

1. Open Terminal (`Applications`->`Utilities`->`Terminal.app`)
2. Type the command `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

To uninstall your Xcode 3.2.4 under `/Developer-3.2.4`:

1. Open Terminal (`Applications`->`Utilities`->`Terminal.app`)
2. Type the command `sudo /Developer-3.2.4/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Reference:
[How to remove Xcode from your Mac](http://idoitonamac.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-remove-xcode-from-your-mac.html)

Comment: Also the newer xcode will not be able to build for apps earlier than 10.7 unless you add the sdks. Which can be found in the older version of xcode. I have kept my old xcode for this purpose and symlink to the sdks inside it